# Can you load data into a MySQL table while "counting" repeated values found in multiple columns combined into one?

Tags: sql, mysql

sorry for the confusing title but I hope this explains my question.

I have a tab delimited text file that looks like this if I were to display it as a table:

```
 ════════╤════════╤════════╤═════════╤═════════╤═════════╤═════════ 
  item   │ id     │ info   │ PERSON1 │ PERSON2 │ PERSON3 │ PERSON4  
 ════════╪════════╪════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════ 
  [data] │ [data] │ [data] │ YES     │ NO      │ NO      │ N/A      
 ────────┼────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────── 
  [data] │ [data] │ [data] │ NO      │ N/A     │ NO      │ N/A      
 ════════╧════════╧════════╧═════════╧═════════╧═════════╧═════════
```

My issue is I have *hundreds* of these **"PERSON_X"** columns. I want to upload this file into MySQL but in a way where I can combine the "person" columns into individual counts, like so:

```
 ════════╤════════╤════════╤════════════╤═══════════╤════════════ 
  item   │ id     │ info   │ PERSON_YES │ PERSON_NO │ PERSON N/A  
 ════════╪════════╪════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪════════════ 
  [data] │ [data] │ [data] │ 1          │ 2         │ 1           
 ────────┼────────┼────────┼────────────┼───────────┼──────────── 
  [data] │ [data] │ [data] │ 0          │ 2         │ 2           
 ════════╧════════╧════════╧════════════╧═══════════╧════════════
```

Is there a way to do this? I am inexperienced/learning. The data found in the "PERSON_X" columns will always be 'YES', 'NO', or "n/a". What can I do?

I tried creating and uploading a table to start and possibly work from there, but there are way too many columns to establish in the "CREATE TABLE" command that it became infeasible. I have tried to look into different methods of loading the data, but it hasn't gone well so I am trying my luck asking here.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in pure SQL?  If you're able to loop through the `PERSONX` columns you can use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: I have thousands of rows, is there a way I can automate this INSERT ON DUPLICATE process while uploading my text?

Comment: I would write a script in Python (or whatever your favorite language is) to process the data file into a new data file with the summary values. Then load that new file into the database. This task will be far easier to do in code. Every language has a common library package you can use to read tab delimited data files and loop over the columns of each line read.

Comment: Alternative would be to load the csv file into  a temporary table (or use csv table engine) as is and use insert ... select ... on duplicate key update... to import the data into the final table.

Answer (score 2):

It will be wordy, but you can do it by assigning the fields of the file to user variables.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename'
INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
(item, id, info, @person1, @person2, @person3, ...)
SET person_yes = (@person1 = 'YES') + (@person2 = 'YES') + (@person3 = 'YES') + ...,
    person_no = (@person1 = 'NO') + (@person2 = 'NO') + (@person3 = 'NO') + ...,
    person_na = (@person1 = 'N/A') + (@person2 = 'N/A') + (@person3 = 'N/A') + ...
```

As suggested in a comment, this will be easier in a programming language that has arrays that you can loop over, instead of having to define hundreds of variables that you have to name explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 3 additional columns in your excel file

For PERSON_YES, PERSON_NO and PERSON_NA

and define the formulas of

- `=COUNTIF(D2:I2,"YES")`
- `=COUNTIF(D3:I3,"YES")`
- `=COUNTIF(D2:I2,"NO")`
- `=COUNTIF(D3:I3,"NO")`
- `=COUNTIF(D2:I2,"N/A")`
- `=COUNTIF(D3:I3,"N/A")`

the first two formulas being for `YES`, `NO` and `N/A` respectively, of course you can adjust the range to your thousands as well as the rows if you have more rows. Then you can create the formula of

```
=CONCAT("insert into yourtable(id, item, info, person_yes, person_no, person_na) values('", B2, "', '", A2, "', '", C2, "', ", J2, ", ", K2, ", ", L2, ");")
```

for the second row and drag the rule downwards to generate the script for all your records (the last 3 items will be different for you instead of J2, K2 and L2 due to the differences between the number of columns), resulting in scripts like this:

```
insert into yourtable(id, item, info, person_yes, person_no, person_na) values('1', 'first', 'inf1', 3, 2, 1);
insert into yourtable(id, item, info, person_yes, person_no, person_na) values('2', 'second', 'inf2', 1, 3, 2);
```

See

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can also load the raw data into a raw table in MySQL, then transform and load the data into a new table.
Here are the steps:
First of all,let's create a raw_table:

```
create table raw_table (item varchar(20),id varchar(20),info varchar(20),PERSON1 varchar(20),PERSON2 varchar(20), PERSON3 varchar(20),PERSON4 varchar(20));
```

Then,let's load it with data from excel. This is done using `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement. However,to simplify the case, here we simply use a INSERT statement.

```
insert raw_table values('data' , 'data' , 'data' , 'YES' ,'NO' ,'NO' ,'N/A'),
('data' , 'data' , 'data' , 'NO'   ,'N/A','NO','N/A');    
  
select * from raw_table;
-- result
+------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| item | id   | info | PERSON1 | PERSON2 | PERSON3 | PERSON4 |
+------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| data | data | data | YES     | NO      | NO      | N/A     |
| data | data | data | NO      | N/A     | NO      | N/A     |
+------+------+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Next, we build the new table and populate it using the data transformed from the raw table.

```
create table new_table (item varchar(20),id   varchar(20),info varchar(20),PERSON_YES int, PERSON_NO int, `PERSON N/A` int); 

insert into new_table
select item,id,info,
(case person1 when 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person2 when 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person3 when 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person4 when 'YES' then 1 else 0 end) as PERSON_YES,
(case person1 when 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person2 when 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person3 when 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person4 when 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) as PERSON_NO,
(case person1 when 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person2 when 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person3 when 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) + (case person4 when 'N/A' then 1 else 0 end) as `PERSON NA`
from test;

select * from new_table;
-- result
+------+------+------+------------+-----------+------------+
| item | id   | info | PERSON_YES | PERSON_NO | PERSON N/A |
+------+------+------+------------+-----------+------------+
| data | data | data |          1 |         2 |          1 |
| data | data | data |          0 |         2 |          2 |
+------+------+------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Personally, I think it can be easier to manipulate data in the RDBMS after the raw data is loaded than directly transformed and loaded from a foreign source.  Besides, as long as we have the raw data, we can transform and load it into different tables based on different requirements.